# How does TDS on FDs work?

Tags: income-tax, india, debt

1. I know TDS happens on accrued interest. If I have a 5-year FD, the bank deducts TDS every March 31 for the interest accrued in that financial year, though I haven't received it yet. But what about the remaining 20%? Is that due every year as well, or when the FD matures?
2. Is the TDS 10% or 10.3%? In other words, does the education cess apply to the TDS? I did some Google searches, and different sites say different things.
3. Do I have to pay 20.6% or 20.9%?

I'm in the 30.9% tax bracket, and my FD interest is more than ₹10K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what about the remaining 20%? Is that due every year as well, or when the FD matures?

It is due every year and not on maturity.

> Is the TDS 10% or 10.3%? In other words, does the education cess apply to the TDS?

That depends on how the financial institution has interpreted the rule book.

> Do I have to pay 20.6% or 20.9%?

It is irrelevant what percentage was deducted. Compute the total tax, you know the TDS pay the balance as Advance Tax or Self Assessment tax.